# Use netsh to show enabled firewall rules only

Tags: windows, firewall, netsh

I'm using the following command to list firewall rules

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule dir=in name=all
```

How can I display enabled rules only? There's no switch like `enabled=true`

Answer (score 3):

`netsh advfirewall` is not recommended anymore and might be deprecated in future versions of Windows (see the warning message when you enter `netsh advfirewall`).

Additionally, I'm not aware of an "enabled" switch in `netsh advfirewall firewall`

I suggest you use Powershell to get the list of enabled inbound rules :

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -Enabled True
```

Comment: It does not print the details of the rules, e.g IP list, port number

Answer (score 2):

I think this Powershell command might be useful in your case:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule dir=in name=all | Select-String -Pattern 'Yes' -Exclude "Edge traversal" -AllMatches -Context 2,11
```